# Form API submit handler does not get called

Tags: forms

I am using FAPI with dynamic fields. The code I am using is:

```
function email_action($form, &$form_state) {

$result = db_query('Select * from my_action_plan_settings ORDER BY action_type');
$records = array();
foreach ($result as  $record) {
  $records[] = $record->poa;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($records) ; $i++) {

  $form['action'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Action #@num', array('@num' => $i)),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['action'][$i]['poa'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Point of Action'),
    '#default_value' => $point_of_actions[$i],
    '#description' => t("Enter first name."),
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['action'][$i]['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email Address'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );

}

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
);

return $form;

}

function email_action_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dsm($form_state);
}
```

The submit handler never gets called, I used a custom submit handler also, it does not get called. If I limit the count of loop to 20, the submit handler gets called and everything works fine but without breaking the for loop, the submit handler never get called, is there a limit to number of fields? Or am I doing something wrong. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hello. Please provide your whole code, trimmed to be [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We can't begin to guess what's wrong with your hooks and handlers when we can't see their definitions.

Comment: sorry, i have updated the code

Comment: No problem. Looks better now :)

Comment: Any errors in the dblog? Located at /admin/reports/dblog

Comment: no errors in dblog, i got it working, the problem is dsm, ddebug_backtrace, debug_print_backtrace, var_dump, print_r,  does not get displayed on the screen, is that any server setting ?  i wrote the code for db insert in submit handler and db inserts are made properly. still dont know why other functions dont display on screen.

Comment: DSM should print to the messages area. Are you sure you have messages area activated in your theme?

Comment: Try also DPM, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046912/what-are-the-differences-between-dpm-and-dsm

Comment: drupal_set_message() works fine, dpm also does not print.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
 function email_action($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['#submit'][] = 'email_action_submit';

    }


    //submit function for the form

    function email_action_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    // write your submit code here
    }
```

Comment: thx harsh, i have tried that too, but does not get called when the entire loop is ran. works if i break in between the loop.